# Fisher Exact Test Question

Tags: self-study, fishers-exact-test

I have:
Group A using **T method** and Group B using **E method**.

Out of a total of 36 possible problem issues.

Group A using T method finds = **26** issues. 
Group B using E method finds = **28** issues.

How do I input the above data in a Fisher Exact Test to find a P-value.?
It should give a **P-value of 0.786**

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I've added a self-study tag.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer myself. 
The data was entered into a 2x2 Fisher Table as

26,28
10,8  ->

**(36 issues minus 26 found = 10, and 36 issues minus 28 found = 8)**

Result gave the **0.786**